# Setting property to disable ehcache at tomcat startup

Tags: java, tomcat, ehcache, system-properties

I am new to this project and still figuring many things out. Been an experienced web developer for many years now.

My QA people came to me and said, "We're having an issue. We used to be able to turn off hibernate caching on our QA boxes to run queries outside of the app and then see the results in the app, but it's not working any more."

So I look into the problem and they we adding the following line to setenv.bat (Tomcat 7 running on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard),

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true
```

and this, according to them used to work, but now it doesn't.

So, problem one, is that we don't run the app in the same way on our dev boxes than on QA and in production. (I know, I know.) We run maven scripts to start everything and I can get the java opts thing to work just fine.

Funnily, I've been doing this for years and I didn't know anything about setenv.bat. I did some reading here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt and it says that setenv.bat doesn't work when running tomcat as a service.

So, I log onto the QA box and dig and find out, sure enough, tomcat is running as a service. The service starts tomcat7.exe //RS//Tomcat7. (Not sure what the tomcat7.exe is.)

So according to the above doc, I set CATALINA_OPTS=-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true and restart the server.

In the meantime, I've written a handy little servlet that dumps all of the system properties, so I can know immediately what effect my changes have. I run it and it says `net.sf.ehcache.disabled=false`. Clearly, something is overriding my change.

So I do some reading here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html and set an environment variable to be PR_JvmOptions=-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true and restart the server. Run my little servlet and:

```
net.sf.ehcache.disabled=false
```

So, clearly, something is overriding my settings no matter what I do. The docs say it is ignoring setenv.bat and I don't know where else to look to find this override.

Comment: @Michael Aw, c'mon, a diary entry starts with "Dear Diary," That makes this completely different. :)

Comment: look for any properties file

Comment: @EugèneAdell Found a couple in the bin directory and inside the application. None set ehcache.disabled.

Comment: Disabling the cache entirely is a bit sad. Can't they use JMX to clear the cache when they do a DB change? (or just restart tomcat...)